# simple function to read input and save in stack (x86_64 assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86-64

i'm trying to build a function in GAS assembly that will read user input, and save that input char-by-char into the stack
thats my code so far:

```
global main

.section .data
buffer: .zero 1
buffend:.quad buffend - buffer

.text
main:
xor %r15,%r15
.l:
    mov $0,%rax
    mov $0,%rdi
    leaq buffer,%rsi
    mov (buffend),%rdx
    syscall
    
    push (buffer)
   cmp $0x0,(buffer)
    jne .l
    je .end
```

but it never ends... any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Where is the label .end?

Comment: There's no exit system call or `ret` instruction, so the only way it could end would be falling through the end and crashing.  Also, `cmp $0x0, (buffer)` is a 4-byte compare.  GAS is bad and doesn't warn about the ambiguous operand-size.  Why are you checking the input data for `0` instead of checking the read system call's return value?  Are you implementing something like `sort -0` that takes uses `'\0'` as a separator in the data?